# Calculate Growth Percentage Resulting in 0

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that store total account of a product every last day of a month. From that table, I want to calculate how much the account growing in percentage. My table looks like this

| PERIOD | GROUP_PRODUCT | ACCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 | DEPOSITO | 22860 |
| 2022-02-26 | DEPOSITO | 22848 |
| 2022-03-31 | DEPOSITO | 22555 |
| 2022-04-30 | DEPOSITO | 22297 |
| 2022-05-31 | DEPOSITO | 22281 |

And below is my query for calculating the growth percentage

```
SELECT *
       ,  DIFF / ACC_YSTR GROWTH_PERCENTAGE
FROM(
SELECT *
       , (ACCOUNT - ACC_YSTR) DIFF
FROM(
SELECT PERIOD
       , GROUP_PRODUCT
       , ACCOUNT
       , COALESCE(LAG(ACCOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_PRODUCT ORDER BY PERIOD ASC), ACCOUNT) ACC_YSTR
FROM BASE_TABLE
))
```

But the problem is, my result for the growth percentage always resulting in 0. How to get the right result?

This is my dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/7kWmsvxM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH BASE_TABLE(PERIOD, GROUP_PRODUCT, ACCOUNT) AS(
VALUES
(DATE('2022-01-31'), 'DEPOSITO',    22860),
(DATE('2022-02-26'), 'DEPOSITO',    22848),
(DATE('2022-03-31'), 'DEPOSITO',    22555),
(DATE('2022-04-30'), 'DEPOSITO',    22297),
(DATE('2022-05-31'), 'DEPOSITO',    22281)
)

SELECT *
       ,  1.0*DIFF / ACC_YSTR GROWTH_PERCENTAGE
FROM(
SELECT *
       , (ACCOUNT - ACC_YSTR) DIFF
FROM(
SELECT PERIOD
       , GROUP_PRODUCT
       , ACCOUNT
       , COALESCE(LAG(ACCOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_PRODUCT ORDER BY PERIOD ASC), ACCOUNT) ACC_YSTR
FROM BASE_TABLE
))
```

| PERIOD | GROUP_PRODUCT | ACCOUNT | ACC_YSTR | DIFF | GROWTH_PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 | DEPOSITO | 22860 | 22860 | 0 | 0.0000000000000000000 |
| 2022-02-26 | DEPOSITO | 22848 | 22860 | -12 | -0.0005249343832020997 |
| 2022-03-31 | DEPOSITO | 22555 | 22848 | -293 | -0.0128238795518207282 |
| 2022-04-30 | DEPOSITO | 22297 | 22555 | -258 | -0.0114387053868321879 |
| 2022-05-31 | DEPOSITO | 22281 | 22297 | -16 | -0.0007175853253800959 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gAz3CrfN)